# vue3: runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:33 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')

Tags: vuejs3

Rookie in Vue3, and i wrote a very simple code like below, and it will throw error:

**runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:33 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')**

If i put the `let productsRef = await fetchProducts();` into onMounted hooks, everything works fine.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { fetchProducts } from '@/services/product.ts';
import { Ref } from 'vue';
import { IProduct } from '@/interfaces/product.interface.ts';

let productsRef: Ref<IProduct[]> = await fetchProducts();
</script>

<template>
  <div class="px-4 py-6" v-if="productsRef">a</div>
</template>
```

Comment: I have been running into the same issue, and apparently the error only shows up for `await` calls. If I get the API response from a static file, everything works as expected. There are so many reasons this issue has been reported for and there is no direct answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems my issue is related to the return value of fetchProducts, it seems i shouldn't use await for a return value of ref

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because the component needs to be wrapped in a Suspense block.

From the docs:

> async setup() must be used in combination with Suspense, which is currently still an experimental feature

https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#top-level-await

---

You can see in the following example that everything works fine until you remove the suspense component from App.vue at which point you'll receive an error.

[play.vuejs example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems my issue is related to the return value of fetchProducts